# Symfony: get result of both tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I want to use the following mysql query: `select * from x join y on x.y_id = y.id where x.a= 0`

I tried to put it in my Symfony project with the following doctrine syntax.

```
$repositoryX->createQueryBuilder('x')
         ->add('select', 'x')
         ->add('from', 'AppBundle:X x')
         ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Y', 'y', 'WITH', 'x.y_id = y.id')
         ->where('x.a = :a')
         ->setParameter('a', 0)
         ->getQuery()
         ->getResult();
```

My problem is that I only see the results of table x, but I also want the results of table y (because of the join on). When I put an extra select, I get `Neither the property "y_id" nor one of the methods "y_id()", "gety_id()"/"isy_id()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class`

The '*' doesn't workin within doctrine .

Comment: What happens when you try `leftJoin('AppBundle:Y', 'y', 'WITH', 'x = y')`?

Comment: What does `$repositoryX->createQueryBuilder()->select('x,y')->from('AppBundle:X','x')->join('x.y', 'y')->where('x.a = :a')->setParameter('a', 0)->getQuery()->getResult()` return?

Comment: Consider checking the docs for how to build a doctrine dql query.  So many mistakes in your posted code.  Don't know where to even start.  Though @ccKep might be on the right track.

Comment: @ccKep I get `Type error: Too few arguments to function.` But aren't we missing an another 'AppBundle:Y' Since we use y, but haven't initialised it?

Comment: @Cerad I used the doctrine documentation to write this 'query'. But maybe not in the best manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting `x` change:

```
->add('select', 'x')
```

to

```
->add('select', 'x,y')
//The second param might accept and array i dont remember off hand
->add('select', ['x','y'])
```

Or written better:

```
$repository->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select(['x','y'])
    ->from('AppBundle:X','x')
    ->join('x.y','y') // This assumes you have the mapping defined for this property
    ->where('x.a = :a')
    ->setParameter('a', 0)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

If you are using annotation mapping it should look something like

```
//X entity

//...
class X {

    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Y")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="y_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $y;
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help :)